# Modular Arithmetic with Indices

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I find $x$ where $\displaystyle 10^{33} \equiv x (\mod 13)$?

I have an exam coming up and I'm not sure how to do this. I am assuming this can be done without a calculator but if not could someone tell me otherwise? I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 13\!:\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv -3} \Rightarrow \color{#c00}{10}^{3n}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-3})^{3n}\equiv (-27)^n\equiv (-1-2\cdot 13)^n\equiv (-1)^n$

Comment: Could you please do it out so I can see how it is done I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: @user1552404 It *is* done. Put $\,n=11\,$ for your special case.

Comment: Oh ye I see it now ha okay thanks